# Measuring the area between two curves

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How do I measure the area between two curves that overlap at one point? Both curves are of different lengths so I would assume that I would first have to limit the range? I am trying to calculate the absolute difference between the curves.

The data for both curves:

```
x1 = {-0.221848749616356, -0.207584055650315, -0.193319361684274, 
-0.179054667718233, -0.164789973752192, -0.150525279786150, 
-0.136260585820109, -0.121995891854068, -0.107731197888027, 
-0.0934665039219856, -0.0792018099559444, -0.0649371159899032, 
-0.0506724220238620, -0.0364077280578208, -0.0221430340917796, 
-0.00787834012573838, 0.00638635384030281, 0.0206510478063440, 
  0.0349157417723852, 0.0491804357384264, 0.0634451297044676, 
  0.0777098236705088, 0.0919745176365500, 0.106239211602591 , 
  0.120503905568632, 0.134768599534674, 0.149033293500715, 
  0.163297987466756, 0.177562681432797, 0.191827375398838, 
  0.206092069364880, 0.220356763330921 , 0.234621457296962, 
  0.248886151263003 , 0.263150845229044, 0.277415539195086, 
  0.291680233161127, 0.305944927127168, 0.320209621093209, 
  0.334474315059250, 0.348739009025292, 0.363003702991333, 
  0.377268396957374, 0.391533090923415, 0.405797784889456, 
  0.420062478855498 , 0.434327172821539, 0.448591866787580, 
  0.462856560753621, 0.477121254719662}

y1 = {0.2266, 0.1878, 0.1510, 0.1159, 0.0826, 0.0509, 
  0.0208, -0.0079, -0.0351, -0.0611, -0.0857, -0.1092, -0.1315, 
-0.1527, -0.1728, -0.1920, -0.2102, -0.2276, -0.2441, -0.2598, 
-0.2747, -0.2889, -0.3024, -0.3152, -0.3274, -0.3390, -0.3500, 
-0.3605, -0.3705, -0.3800, -0.3890, -0.3976, -0.4058, -0.4136, 
-0.4210, -0.4280, -0.4347, -0.4410, -0.4470, -0.4528, -0.4583, 
-0.4635, -0.4684, -0.4731, -0.4776, -0.4818, -0.4859, -0.4897, 
-0.4934, -0.4968}

x2 = {-0.425195987318646, -0.379438496757971, -0.338045811599746, 
-0.300257250710346, -0.265495144451134, -0.233310461079733, 
-0.175318514102046, -0.148989575379697, -0.100684895805142, 
-0.0572192020240517, -0.0177106607403781, 0.0185015119140666, 
  0.0519252674010163, 0.0976827579616914, 0.139075443119917, 
  0.176864004009316, 0.222621494569991, 0.264014179728217, 
  0.301802740617616, 0.344837372842818, 0.383989496804966, 
  0.426741477225916, 0.465659543256286, 0.507052228414511, 
  0.544840789303911}

y2 = {1.98977028898017, 1.61591642101008, 1.32130458152091, 
  1.08402347810582 , 0.889420233704868, 0.727354573106834, 
  0.473895440336041, 0.373297476340392, 0.209165818511101, 
  0.0814476833288233, -0.0203553720851161, -0.103127353871147, 
-0.171554952110805, -0.254243003377083, -0.319404503563252, 
-0.371885736806178, -0.427585958833350, -0.471479967367961, 
-0.506832310289645, -0.542268987260499, -0.570576160634482, 
-0.597734852914923, -0.619460166116272, -0.639813078961169, 
-0.656205365251891}
```

[image: DataPic]

Comment: Can you please post the data in your post, properly edited in code blocks? Or at least, post the code that would allow us to generate the points?

Comment: Also edit question to define how you want area to be measured? Are both regions positive or is one negative? Which?

Comment: You could use `InterpolatingFunction` and `NIntegrate`.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful -- using semicolons to suppress irrelevant output would be considerate, too.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the area you are interested in,

```
plot = ListLinePlot[Transpose /@ {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Extract it using `Cases`,

```
inBetween = Cases[Normal@plot, _Polygon, Infinity];
Graphics@inBetween
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And then just grab the `Area`,

```
Total[Area /@ inBetween]
(* 0.0956571 *)
```

You can get a similar answer by making an interpolating function and integrating:

```
funcs = Interpolation@*Transpose /@ {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}};
NIntegrate[
 Abs[funcs[[1]][x] - funcs[[2]][x]], {x, -0.221848749616356`, 
  0.477121254719662`}]
(* 0.0952311 *)
```

Comment: I would also like to calculate whether there is a significant difference between the two curves but only for the area. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - what do you mean by "significant difference"?

Comment: @TimShepard Do you mean the ratio between the black area and the are under one of the curves? If it's small, it means both curves are similar. Kind of a relative error (don't forget the absolute values).

Comment: @anderstood - feel free to edit this answer if you understand the question more, I made it a wiki :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
x1 = {-0.221848749616356, -0.207584055650315, -0.193319361684274, \
-0.179054667718233, -0.164789973752192, -0.150525279786150, \
-0.136260585820109, -0.121995891854068, -0.107731197888027, \
-0.0934665039219856, -0.0792018099559444, -0.0649371159899032, \
-0.0506724220238620, -0.0364077280578208, -0.0221430340917796, \
-0.00787834012573838, 0.00638635384030281, 0.0206510478063440, 
   0.0349157417723852, 0.0491804357384264, 0.0634451297044676, 
   0.0777098236705088, 0.0919745176365500, 0.106239211602591, 
   0.120503905568632, 0.134768599534674, 0.149033293500715, 0.163297987466756,
    0.177562681432797, 0.191827375398838, 0.206092069364880, 
   0.220356763330921, 0.234621457296962, 0.248886151263003, 0.263150845229044,
    0.277415539195086, 0.291680233161127, 0.305944927127168, 
   0.320209621093209, 0.334474315059250, 0.348739009025292, 0.363003702991333,
    0.377268396957374, 0.391533090923415, 0.405797784889456, 
   0.420062478855498, 0.434327172821539, 0.448591866787580, 0.462856560753621,
    0.477121254719662};
y1 = {0.2266, 0.1878, 0.1510, 0.1159, 0.0826, 0.0509, 
   0.0208, -0.0079, -0.0351, -0.0611, -0.0857, -0.1092, -0.1315, -0.1527, \
-0.1728, -0.1920, -0.2102, -0.2276, -0.2441, -0.2598, -0.2747, -0.2889, \
-0.3024, -0.3152, -0.3274, -0.3390, -0.3500, -0.3605, -0.3705, -0.3800, \
-0.3890, -0.3976, -0.4058, -0.4136, -0.4210, -0.4280, -0.4347, -0.4410, \
-0.4470, -0.4528, -0.4583, -0.4635, -0.4684, -0.4731, -0.4776, -0.4818, \
-0.4859, -0.4897, -0.4934, -0.4968};
x2 = {-0.425195987318646, -0.379438496757971, -0.338045811599746, \
-0.300257250710346, -0.265495144451134, -0.233310461079733, \
-0.175318514102046, -0.148989575379697, -0.100684895805142, \
-0.0572192020240517, -0.0177106607403781, 0.0185015119140666, 
   0.0519252674010163, 0.0976827579616914, 0.139075443119917, 
   0.176864004009316, 0.222621494569991, 0.264014179728217, 0.301802740617616,
    0.344837372842818, 0.383989496804966, 0.426741477225916, 
   0.465659543256286, 0.507052228414511, 0.544840789303911};
y2 = {1.98977028898017, 1.61591642101008, 1.32130458152091, 1.08402347810582, 
   0.889420233704868, 0.727354573106834, 0.473895440336041, 0.373297476340392,
    0.209165818511101, 
   0.0814476833288233, -0.0203553720851161, -0.103127353871147, \
-0.171554952110805, -0.254243003377083, -0.319404503563252, \
-0.371885736806178, -0.427585958833350, -0.471479967367961, \
-0.506832310289645, -0.542268987260499, -0.570576160634482, \
-0.597734852914923, -0.619460166116272, -0.639813078961169, \
-0.656205365251891};
```

The sets of points are

```
pts1 = Transpose[{x1, y1}];
pts2 = Transpose[{x2, y2}];
```

The [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) functions are

```
f1 = Interpolation[pts1];
f2 = Interpolation[pts2];
```

The regions are

```
Show[
 Plot[
  {Tooltip[f1[x], "f1"], f2[x]},
  {x, Min[x1], Max[x1]},
  PlotStyle -> Blue,
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {LightRed, LightBlue}}}],
 Plot[
  Tooltip[f2[x], "f2"],
  {x, Min[x2], Max[x2]},
  PlotStyle -> Red],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Red minus Blue

```
area1 = NIntegrate[f2[x] - f1[x],
  {x, Min[x1], Max[x1]}]

0.050805
```

Red plus Blue

```
area2 = NIntegrate[Abs[f1[x] - f2[x]],
  {x, Min[x1], Max[x1]}]

0.0952311
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one interpretation of the (absolute) area between the connected dots:

```
Area@Polygon[Join[Transpose[{x1, y1}], Reverse@Transpose[{x2, y2}]]]
(*  0.131786  *)
```

[image]

Comment: The OP does not explain clearly what area he is looking for; this "extrapolates"  the short curve to join the long curve, which explains the discrepancy with the other solutions which truncate the domain to the smallest.

Comment: @anderstood Yes, quite right. It's not clear what "between the curves" means exactly.  (There aren't even any curves defined in the question, which is why I emphasized connecting the dots.)

Comment: It's simple enough to restrict the region in this answer to range of x with a `Rectangle`: `Area[RegionIntersection[DiscretizeRegion@Rectangle[{Max[Min /@ {x1, x2}], -1}, {Min[Max /@ {x1, x2}], 2}], DiscretizeRegion@Polygon[Join[Transpose[{x1, y1}], Reverse@Transpose[{x2, y2}]]]]]`