# Finding the area enclosed by two curves

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, area, curves

I am trying to find the area enclosed between two curves (i.e., two datasets).

The challenge is to estimate the cross-sectional area.
[image]
as indicated in blue.

The first dataset represents the bathymetry of the water channel.

The other dataset represents the water surface level.

I followed the example in this post: [Measuring the area between two curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132374/measuring-the-area-between-two-curves)
but I obtained negative result (-8.48313). I realized that I receive negative area in the case of low water level.

```
bathy={{-2.8, 2.611}, {-0.18, 0.991}, {0., 0.665}, {5.35, 0.},{12.08, 0.482}, {21.51, 0.78}, {30.92, 0.807}, {40.44, 0.692},{49.47,0.592}};

lev={{-2.8, 0.5}, {-0.18, 0.5}, {0., 0.5}, {5.35, 0.5}, {12.08,0.5}, {21.51, 0.5}, {30.92, 0.5}, {40.44, 0.5}, {49.47, 0.5}}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

- We filling the `bathy` to `Top` and filling the `lev` to `Bottom` to get two regions and calculate the `Area` of their `RegionIntersection`.

```
reg1 = ListPlot[bathy, Filling -> Top, Joined -> True, 
   MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Green];
reg2 = ListPlot[lev, Filling -> Bottom, Joined -> True, 
   MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Yellow];
reg12 = RegionIntersection[DiscretizeGraphics@reg1, 
   DiscretizeGraphics@reg2];
Area[reg12]
Show[reg1, reg2, Graphics[{Blue, reg12}]]
```

> `2.75384`

[image]

- Here we test another data. We try to calculate the area of two curves crossing each other,but the code need to be updated.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
bathy = Table[{x, Sin[π*x]^2 E^-x}, {x, 0, 5, .1}];
lev = Table[{x, Cos[π*x]^2 E^-x}, {x, -1, 3, .1}];
plot = ListPlot[{bathy, lev}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All];
intersection = 
  SortBy[RegionIntersection[Line[bathy], Line[lev]][[1]], First];
regs = Table[
   Polygon@Join[{intersection[[i]]}, 
     Select[bathy, 
      intersection[[i, 1]] <= First@# <= 
        intersection[[i + 1, 1]] &], {intersection[[i + 1]]}, 
     Reverse@Select[lev, 
       intersection[[i, 1]] <= First@# <= 
         intersection[[i + 1, 1]] &]], {i, 1, 
    Length@intersection - 1}];
Area[regs] // Total
Graphics[{Cyan, regs, plot[[1]]}, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> True]
```

> `0.43827`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear! Are you looking for the signed or unsigned area?

```
poly = Polygon[Join[ bathy , Reverse[lev] ]]
Area[poly]   (*unsigned area 13.9908 *)
Show[{ListPlot[{bathy, lev}, PlotRange -> All],Graphics[{ FaceForm[Lighter[Gray]], poly }]}]
```

[image]

Check result

```
ip1 = Interpolation[bathy, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
ip2 = Interpolation[lev, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
NIntegrate[RealAbs[ip1[x] - ip2[x]], {x, Min[bathy[[All, 1]]],Max[bathy[[All, 1]]]}]  
(* unsigned area 13.9908*)

NIntegrate[ ip1[x] - ip2[x] , {x, Min[bathy[[All, 1]]],Max[bathy[[All, 1]]]}]  
(* signed area 8.48313 *)
```

Comment: I want to obtain the area shsaded in blue.
I think -8.48313 is incorrect in my case.

Comment: @Mehmet Thanks for the edit of your question. Now it's much clearer. The area you are looking for ist `NIntegrate[ (ip2[x] - ip1[x]) Boole[ip2[x] >= ip1[x]] , {x, 
  Min[bathy[[All, 1]]], Max[bathy[[All, 1]]]}] (*2.75383*)`

Answer (score 0):

Using the method from the [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132374/measuring-the-area-between-two-curves) linked in the post:

```
bathy = {{-2.8, 2.611}, {-0.18, 0.991}, {0., 0.665}, {5.35, 0.}, {12.08, 0.482}, {21.51, 0.78}, {30.92, 0.807}, {40.44, 0.692}, {49.47, 0.592}};
lev = {{-2.8, 0.5}, {-0.18, 0.5}, {0., 0.5}, {5.35, 0.5}, {12.08, 0.5}, {21.51, 0.5}, {30.92, 0.5}, {40.44, 0.5}, {49.47, 0.5}};

ip1 = Interpolation[bathy, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
ip2 = Interpolation[lev, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

NIntegrate[
 Max[(ip2[x] - ip1[x]), 0], {x, Min[lev[[All, 1]]], Max[lev[[All, 1]]]}]
```

> 2.75383

Visualizing what is being integrated:

```
Plot[Max[(ip2[x] - ip1[x]), 0], {x, Min[lev[[All, 1]]], Max[lev[[All, 1]]]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]